# Check String Contains in SQL Server CE

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-ce

Table names `table1`, `table2`.

- `table1` has these columns: `compno`, `compname`
- `table2` has these columns: `userno`, `username`, `accesscompno`

Table1:

```
compno compname
----------------
1        A
2        B
3        C
```

Table2:

```
userno username accesscompno
-----------------------------
0        Admin      1,2,3
1        1          2,3
2        2           1,2
```

`accesscompno` is a `nvarchar` data type. I have company no and user no now check it that user had permission for access this company.

How to check it?

Am new to `Sql server Ce`. 
So tell how solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

Never save ***comma separated values*** in a column!! which violates `1NF` first rule of normalization. Please think about changing the data structure.

Create a *Junction* table that links the `user` and `company`

```
create table user_acccess
(
user_acccess_id int identity(1,1),
user_no int, -- foreign key mapped with user table
compno int -- foreign key mapped with company table
)
```

Now a simple `select` query is all needed for your requirement

```
select * 
from user_acccess 
where userno = 'some user'
  and compno = 'some company'
```

still you want to work with your current table structure then try this

```
;with cte as
(
SELECT userno,
       username,
       Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') compno
FROM   (SELECT userno,
               username,
               Cast ('<M>' + Replace(accesscompno, ' ', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS Data
        FROM   [table2]) AS A
       CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a) 
)
select * 
from cte 
where userno = 'some user'
  and compno = 'some company'
```

Comment: thanks sir i will check it and tell. And `1NF first rule of normalization` i konw it sir but i do which is said by my MD. :-(

Comment: @Sathish Did you try the last query

Comment: I will Try it and tell it sir

Comment: Its Show following error `There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 1,Token in error = WITH ]`